# Swift: How to pass a Parameter to a function which itself is also a Parameter?

Tags: swift

It's like this:

```
var i = 0
button.addTarget(self, action:"showContent", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and the function "showContent" is like this:

```
func showContent(i: Int) {
    //do sth.
}
```

I want to pass the variable i to function showContent when that button be touched, how could i do ?

Comment: Just consider to use a member variable, since you are sharing data in the instance.

Comment: I'm surely this would be a solution, but, how can i do that without using a member variable?

Comment: @RangChao You could subclass `UIButton`, but don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the target-action pattern, you can't do that. You can either use `"showContent"`, in which case your function will be:

```
func showContent() {

}
```

… or you can add a colon (`"showContent:"`) in which case your function will be:

```
func showContent(sender : UIButton) {
    // do something with sender
}
```

This helps enforce the broader Model / View / Controller pattern by making it difficult for your views to be "smart". Instead, your model and controller objects should handle `i`. A button simply displays what it's told, and tells your controller when it's tapped.

You can read `i`, and respond to it, in the appropriate method. For example:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var i = 0
    var button = UIButton(type: .System)
    var label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        button.addTarget(self, action:"showContent", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func showContent() {
        i++
        label.text = "Current value of i: \(i)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it seems that i realized what you said, thank you! :)